# Bibliography bibtex style - Autor-year-title-publisher

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

Hey how to change style of bibliography to display information in order  Autor-year-title-publisher? My current style is `acm` and it looks like this
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I edit my post and add picture

Comment: Should the year field, once placed after the author block, be encased in parentheses? Should the year field be set off by commas or periods (aka full stops)? A separate question: Why are the year fields in entries of type @article currently encased in double parentheses?

Comment: Yes year Field in parantheses, separate by comma. I have double parantheses becuase I write year in parantheses in Jabref, I will change it.

Comment: The description of the `acm` bib style says, "A lot like `abbrv.bst`, but names come out "Last, initials", and in `\sc`. Some dates are parenthesized." The file was last updated (other than a licensing adjustment) in 1988. Rather than hack the bst file to achieve your formatting objectives, you should consider running the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package, to create a new bst file that satisfies all of your formatting requirements; open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst` to get started.

Comment: Really there is so much work with it? I think that there is a single command to change order of bibliography :(